# Where can I view the secondary rate limit of GitHub REST api?

Tags: javascript, rest, github, github-api, octokit-js

I'm trying to create something with GitHub's [REST](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) api using [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/), but I'm having trouble dealing with their [secondary rate limit](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/overview/resources-in-the-rest-api#secondary-rate-limits), I wonder where can I view this secondary rate limit, or know exactly how they work? The documentation seems to be very vague about the inner workings of this said **secondary rate limit**.

The **rate limits** can be viewed using the endpoint below, but it does not include the **secondary rate limit**.

```js
await octokit.request('GET /rate_limit', {})
```

Also the documentation only provides [best practices](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/guides/best-practices-for-integrators) to avoid this secondary rate limit, but even this does not help.

Specifically I'm constantly using their [follow a user](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/users/followers#follow-a-user) endpoint every 2 seconds and doing a 5 minute sleep after 24 requests, but at some point I'm still hitting this secondary rate limit.

```js
await octokit.request('PUT /user/following/{username}', {
  username: 'USERNAME'
})
```

At this point, the only solution that I can think of is to slow down even further with the requests, but that is not optimal.

I wonder If GitHub has a way to view this **secondary rate limit** so I can deal with it programmatically, or on a much clearer way?

Comment: I dare say there is a reason why it is intentionally vague, so people don't try to game/exploit it.

Comment: If they wanted this to be known, they would put the details in their documentation.

Comment: I guess that's just how it is, I just find it funny that they are giving a **rate limit** of 5,000 requests per hour for authenticated users, but with my attempt the maximum **rate limit** that I was able to use is around 200+ only because I'm hitting **secondary rate limit**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see [secondary rate limits configured on a on-premise GHE](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.5/admin/configuration/configuring-your-enterprise/configuring-rate-limits#enabling-secondary-rate-limits) (GitHub for Enterprise) instance.

> [image: https://docs.github.com/assets/cb-104985/images/enterprise/management-console/secondary-rate-limits-checkbox.png]
>
> Type limits for:
>
> - Total Requests,
> - CPU Limit, and
> - CPU Limit for Searching,
>
> or accept the pre-filled default limits.

But even that instance does not have an exposed API to configure those elements: web page interface only.

Comment: I see, so information is only given for GHE not for free accounts, that's unfortunate then.